# How do I factor this complex polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My math teacher offered my class extra credit if we could factor this equation. It is not factorable by grouping. If you put the values into a polynomial root solver the zeros are Integer.

Equation: $x(x^3 + 4x^2 -3x -18) = 0$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)?

Comment: there were both + - with the term 3x. What has to be there?

Comment: Why don’t you try to find small integers that are roots of the polynomial?

Comment: Because you have $x$ as a factor, there is one trivial root:
$x(x^3+4x^2-3x-18)=0\implies x=0\ or\ x^3+4x^2-3x-18=0$
The remaining roots are the solutions to the polynomial
$x^3+4x^2-3x-18=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to R. Burton's comment, if you solve $x^3+4x^2-3x-18$,by Rational Root Theorem, possible roots are $\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm6,\pm9,\pm18$. Observe that positive $2$ is a root. Therefore,  $x^3+4x^2-3x-18=(x-2)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is quadratic. Now, $q(x)=(x+3)^2$, giving you all other three roots.
Hence,  $x(x^3+4x^2-3x-18)=x(x-2){(x+3)}^2$

Comment: Corrected: $q(x)=(x+3)^2$

Comment: @z100 Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

$x^3+4x^2-3x-18 = (x^3 +3x^2)+(x^2-3x-18) = x^2(x+3)+(x+3)(x-6)=(x+3)(x^2+x-6)=(x+3)(x+3)(x-2)$